# Good budget headphones

Tags: audio, headphones

Can anyone recommend some good over-ear wired headphones around £50 / €55 / $60 that punch above their weight (pricewise) like the Superlux HD668B did a few years back or the Klipsch Image S4 did a few years before that?

I'm not bothered about noise-cancelling or headset / mic and don't overly care if they're open or closed back. Comfort for two-hour (or more) sessions is a high priority. I'm looking at the Pioneer MS5T but would appreciate any other suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what are your overall expectations but I would probably buy Sennheiser HD 200 for that price. In my country there are not many brands so I usually buy the best Sennheiser headphones in my budget range.

Comment: Appreciate the recommendation. I've tried Sennheisers in the past and didn't like them, but the models I tried were cheaper than these so that's probably why.